# pass npm config into npm scripts entry

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm running my entire project from npm scripts, and i've namespaced a few methods underneath test for clarity. I'd like to use the `silent` level of verbosity for all test related commands instead of the normal, extremely verbose `npm ERR! Exit status 1...`

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run test:unit && npm run test:integration",
    "test:unit": "mocha test/unit",
    "test:integration": "mocha test/integration"
  }
}
```

I've tried including the `--loglevel=silent` in the npm scripts commands, but that does not work.
I do *not* want to enable this for all commands, just for testing related ones, so setting the flag on the environment or in `.npmrc` is not an option (unless there is additional criteria I can define in `.nmprc`).

Answer (score 1):

The  flag `-s` can do that :

**Package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm run test:unit -s && npm run test:integration -s",
    "test:unit": "mocha test/unit",
    "test:integration": "mocha test/integration"
  }
}
```

It just silences output from npm on those tasks.